# How to get all roads around a given location in OpenStreetMap?

Tags: openstreetmap, overpass-api

Cant figure out how to get all roads for the specific radius at the given location. My current query is

```
<query type="way">
    <around lat="55.693309807744484" lon="21.151986122131348" radius="50"/>
</query>
<union>
  <item/>
  <recurse type="down"/>
</union>
<print/>
```

I tried to add something like this `<highway>primary,secondary,tertiary,residential</highway>` but it didn't worked

Comment: describe your "didn't worked" . Any error ?

Comment: @ShivanRaptor just cant parse the query

Comment: @Kirix We can't help you if you don't describe your problem.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

See your query on [overpass turbo](http://overpass-turbo.eu/s/1EY). It *does* return all [ways](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Elements) around the given point. So you seem to have a problem in your parser.

If you want to filter for specific highway types then you have to specify a [tag](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tags) as described in the [Overpass API Language Guide](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API/Language_Guide):

```
<query type="way">
    <around lat="55.693309807744484" lon="21.151986122131348" radius="50"/>
    <has-kv k="highway" regv="trunk|secondary"/>
</query>
<union>
  <item/>
  <recurse type="down"/>
</union>
<print/>
```

(the [result on overpass turbo](http://overpass-turbo.eu/s/1EZ))

See the [highway key](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Key%3ahighway) in the [OpenStreetMap wiki](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org) for an explanation of the different values.