# how to download all roads and nodes in an specific area from openstreetmap.org

Tags: download, maps, openstreetmap

my question is about how to download all roads and nodes in an specific area, for example Manhattan, from openstreetmap.org

Comment: What have you tried so far? There are already many similar questions with answers, for example this one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20323690/1340631

Comment: Alternatively you can look at http://download.geofabrik.de/ they have OSM data extracts for many regions/countries...

Comment: Thank you for your answers. I have download the Manhattan map through the https://extract.bbbike.org where it can create polygon as map boundary.

Answer (score 0):

I have download the Manhattan map through the extract.bbbike.org where it can create polygon as map boundary.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ph1gn.png)